# JQuantlib on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, quantlib

I have been wondering: Has anyone successfully deployed a Google App Engine which uses JQuantlib? [JQuantLib](http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a free, open-source, comprehensive framework for quantitative finance, written in 100% Java.

Does anyone know whether this is possible at all? I understand that libraries need to be whitelisted by google to run on app engine. However I am wondering whether it is possible to build the library from source and send it along with the application - given of course that the dependencies are fulfilled.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload any library you want to App Engine.  It needs to use white-listed java APIs.

From the quick squiz I did on JQuantlib, I can't see any reason why it won't work.  So, go for it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I would also to try this out. Have you been successful with this ?